# In which country might you find a scorpion in your wine?

Tags: wine, ingredients, tradition

**In which country might you find a scorpion in your wine?**

Every country has its own tradition to serve wine; someone asked me that question but I didn't find the answer yet.

Comment: Might depend on if the scorpion went in under his own volition.

Answer (score 3):

Relating to wine, I suspect that the right answer is none.

On the contrary, I read about vodka being quite popular: e.g. see [here](https://www.firebox.com/Scorpion-Vodka/p1468), [here](https://www.thailandunique.com/chinese-scorpion-vodka) (same producer), [here](https://skorppio-vodka.com) and [here](https://www.insectescomestibles.fr/en/26-scorpion-vodka.html)

Comment: Curious if the scorpion is dead and *then* placed in the vodka or inserted alive and then dies.

Answer (score 2):

**China**, although it's not actually grape wine, as most would refer to it.

It's more likely to be some form of rice wine or grain alcohol.

[Ref.](https://www.thedrinksbusiness.com/2014/08/worlds-weirdest-alcoholic-drinks/5/)